# R Shiny app loads, but radio buttons do not select values properly

Tags: html, r, shiny

This is my first time using stack overflow so apologies if I do this wrong.

I'm fairly new to coding in R and I'm trying to make a simple Shiny app using a [TidyTuesday](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/blob/master/data/2021/2021-05-04/readme.md) dataset. I wanted to make a map with points showing the different types of water systems ("water_tech") and radio buttons to choose which type of water system is plotted on the map. I got the app to load without an error message, however no matter which button is selected, all of the different types of water systems are plotted on the map, not just the one I selected (essentially, the buttons don't work). If anyone has any ideas about what could be causing this to happen I would greatly appreciate it!

Reproducible code:

````r
### Load Libraries
library(shiny)
#> Warning: package 'shiny' was built under R version 4.0.4
library(shinythemes)
#> Warning: package 'shinythemes' was built under R version 4.0.4
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(here)
#> here() starts at C:/Users/eruks/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2jxqLH/reprex-2a306cec2120-white-boto
library(rnaturalearth)
#> Warning: package 'rnaturalearth' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(rnaturalearthdata)
#> Warning: package 'rnaturalearthdata' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1


### Load Data
water <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-05-04/water.csv')
#> 
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> cols(
#>   row_id = col_double(),
#>   lat_deg = col_double(),
#>   lon_deg = col_double(),
#>   report_date = col_character(),
#>   status_id = col_character(),
#>   water_source = col_character(),
#>   water_tech = col_character(),
#>   facility_type = col_character(),
#>   country_name = col_character(),
#>   install_year = col_double(),
#>   installer = col_character(),
#>   pay = col_character(),
#>   status = col_character()
#> )


### User Interface
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),
                
                # Application title
                titlePanel("Water Access Points in Africa"),
                
                # Sidebar with radio buttons for choosing which type of water system
                sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        radioButtons(inputId = "water_tech",
                                     label = "Water system:",
                                     choices = c("Hand Pump", "Hydram", "Kiosk", "Mechanized Pump", "Rope and Bucket", "Tapstand"),
                                     selected = "Hand Pump")
                    ),
                    
                    mainPanel(
                        plotOutput("water_plot")
                    )
                )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    
    water_clean <- water %>%
        drop_na(water_tech) %>%
        mutate(water_tech = ifelse(str_detect(water_tech, "Hand Pump"), "Hand Pump", water_tech),
               water_tech = ifelse(str_detect(water_tech, "Mechanized Pump"), "Mechanized Pump", water_tech),
               water_tech = as.factor(water_tech)) %>%
        select(2, 3, 7, 9) %>%
        filter(lon_deg > -25 & lon_deg < 52 & lat_deg > -40 & lat_deg < 35)
    
    africa <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf", continent = "Africa")
    
    rwater <- reactive({
        water_clean %>%
            filter(water_tech == input$water_tech)
    })
    
    output$water_plot <- renderPlot({
        rwater() %>%
            ggplot() +
            geom_sf(data = africa,
                    fill = "#ffffff") +
            geom_point(data = water_clean,
                       aes(x = lon_deg,
                           y = lat_deg,
                           color = water_tech)) +
            theme_bw() +
            theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
                  axis.text = element_blank(),
                  axis.title = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                  panel.border = element_blank()) +
            labs(x = "",
                 y = "")
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

<div style="width: 100% ; height: 400px ; text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;" class="muted well">Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents</div>

<sup>Created on 2021-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>```

Thank you :)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rwater()` has no effect in this code:

```
    rwater() %>%
        ggplot() +
        geom_sf(data = africa,
                fill = "#ffffff") +
        geom_point(data = water_clean,
                   aes(x = lon_deg,
                       y = lat_deg,
                       color = water_tech))
```

because you enter the `water_clean` data in `geom_point`.

I think you want:

```
        ggplot() +
        geom_sf(data = africa,
                fill = "#ffffff") +
        geom_point(data = rwater(),
                   aes(x = lon_deg,
                       y = lat_deg,
                       color = water_tech))
```